# Cannot connect to SSH intermittently , sshd is running, and other services are online and operating without disruption

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization

So when doing this:

```
ssh -l root myKVMinstance.domain.com
```

i get this:

> ssh:  connect to host myKVMinstance.domain.com port 22: Operation timed out

at the same time while that is happening, i am able to ping, connect to apache and tomcat, and those display what i'd expect [the test pages].

Then, after a while, the server is reachable again, as if nothing ever were.

If i was connected via ssh, it would kick me out of my session with a

> "Write failed: Broken pipe" 
>   error.

I am constantly pinging that box, and i get very few packets lost, mostly a single one, and then a large amount of successfully returned ones.

Please help!

This is occuring on a KVM instance, the KVM host os remains reachable throughout the instance's "outage".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the sshd process is dying on you. Try to update or reinstall it using your package manager, or download it from http://www.openssh.org/portable.html

e.g.,

yum -y update openssh-server 
 yum -y remove openssh-server 
 yum -y install openssh-server  

etc.

Comment: tried that. Also trying a mtr -i 0.01 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to see if i can spot some packet loss. Will wait and see until it happens again.

Comment: Does the KVM host OS have SSH? can you connect from the host to the instance?